# Stacking with CONV2D + LSTM

Tags: tensorflow, image-processing, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, lstm

I'm trying to use 2 methods, such as *Conv2D* and LSTM. I have already run ImageDataGenerator code.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3RXS.jpg)

it shows that:
Found 1312 images belonging to 3 classes.
Found 876 images belonging to 3 classes.

My shape training and val is (150,150,1) and (150,150,1).
Here the code for combining Conv2d + LSTM
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jqGFn.jpg)

Aftar I have run program *model_image*, it shows that:
"Input 0 of layer conv2d_76 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=4, found ndim=3. Full shape received: (3000, 150, 1)"

I have already used many ways to handle that error (such as Flatten and Reshape layers). But, the result is same. I don't know how to solve this code. Help me please,
it's such to be honour for help me. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try using the expand_dims() function from TF.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims

Comment: Okey i'll try it. Thank you so much

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? If so try changing the input shape in the first layer after using expand_dims().
(i.e) input_shape=(150, 150, 1, 1)